# Need to add regional bounds for HERE maps. For eg : I want to add the view bounds of the map for a particular city on flutter platform

Tags: flutter, here-api

How can I achieve to show the view bounds on the HERE maps for a particular city on flutter platform?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get bounding box for your city that available in property "boundingBox" of Place object https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-explore/4.6.2.0/api_reference/search/Place/boundingBox.html

To search your city and look at it view bounds use this roughly sample of code (not tested):

```
await (new SearchEngine()).searchByText("DEU Berlin", SearchOptions.withDefaults(),
        (SearchError searchError, List<here.Place> placeList) async {
      if (SearchError == null) {
        here.Place place = placeList.first;
        _hereMapController.camera.lookAtAreaWithOrientation(place.boundingBox, MapCameraOrientationUpdate.withDefaults());
      } else {
        var error = searchError.toString();
      }
    });
```

Additional help links:

https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/master/examples/latest/explore/flutter/camera_app/lib/CameraExample.dart
https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/master/examples/latest/explore/flutter/routing_app/lib/RoutingExample.dart
https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-explore/4.6.2.0/api_reference/mapview/MapCamera/lookAtAreaWithOrientation.html
https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-explore/4.6.2.0/api_reference/search/SearchEngine/searchByText.html